# Switch working copy to a branch without commiting to the original location

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branch, switch-statement, working-copy

I have a slight problem with SVN:

I added some new folders and files to my working copy and wanted to commit those new elements to a developer branch instead of to the real location implied by the folder structure.

With TortoiseSVN I did a "Branch/Tag..." and specified the option "Working copy" in the group "Create copy in the repository from:". The elements got committed to the branch location, but unfortunately, I cannot switch my working copy to this new branch because a commit to the real location hasn't been done yet. My intention was to do further commits to the developer branch and to finally merge the branch with the trunk.

Is there a way around this problem?

Answer (score 2):

One of possible solutions is:

1. save your work to a patch file: `svn diff > my-work.patch`
2. checkout new branch at some other place
3. apply your work to that branch using `patch -p0 -i my-work.patch`
4. commit work

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it.

1. Backup your project. E.g.,copy the folder to an external hard drive.
2. Tag (svn copy) the highest project revision that doesn't contain your changes. The tip of the trunk (or branch) to which you have not yet committed. This will be a server-side copy, URL to URL.
3. Branch (svn copy) the same uncommitted project revision. Server-side copy again.
4. Switch (svn switch) to the new branch.
5. Run svn info to confirm your working copy folder is in fact pointing to the new branch.
6. Commit to the new branch.

Now you'll have a tag of the revision before your changes, a branch to which your latest changes have been committed, and the trunk will remain as it was before your working copy modifications, i.e. equivalent to the tagged revision.